# zur Seite legen

Tags: meaning

Benutzt man die Formulierung

> zur Seite legen

im Sinne - einen Gegenstand auf einen anderen Platz legen?
Ich weiß, dass die Phrase eine figurative Bedeutung hat - Geld zurücklegen, aber ich möchte gerne wissen, ob auch die "wörtliche" Bedeutung im Alltag gebraucht wird oder sagt man eher beiseite legen?

Es gab schon zwar eine Diskussion zum Thema: zur Seite und beiseite. Ich habe da allerdings keine klare Antwort auf meine Frage gefunden.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Natürlich kann man das wörtlich nehmen/verwenden - z.B. in einem Kochrezept:

> Fleisch ausbeinen, Knochen für die Sauce zur Seite legen, Fleisch scharf anbraten.

Comment: Warum nicht `Soße`?

Comment: @AmigoJack Für Muttersprachler: Gourmetrezept ;) - für Lerner: Die Schreibweisen Soße und Sauce sind beide erlaubt und zumindestens für das Kochprodukt gleichwertig

Comment: Warum nicht Soße (wiewohl als Schreibung für Sauce akzeptiert): zum Beispiel weil du dann die Soße in die Sauciere tust... und vielleicht findest du das unschlüssig und tust lieber Sauce rein. Denn eine Soßiere gibt es meines Wissens noch nicht.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Man könnte ja auch ein Soßenkännchen nehmen. Da kann man dann nur Soße reintun? Auf einer Speisekarte dürfte (außer im sehr hemdsärmligen Restaurant) dafür kaum "Soße" auftauchen, während man die *Soße*, die beim Tauwetter auf der Strasse rumfließt, wohl kaum als *Sauce* bezeichnen würde.